# How to broaden coordinates from a location query?

Tags: python, django, geolocation, coordinates, weather-api

I have an application where the user can enter a location query such as :

```
Corinth
```

The application will add a postfix ",Greece" and calculate the latitude and longitude coordinates for the city. So, the query for the coordinates will be `Corinth, Greece`.

After, that the application returns the weather forecast for that location using DarkSkyApi. I want to only return forecasts for my country, which is Greece.

The problem is that if a user types : `London`. Then, the location will return the coordinates of some obscure location in Greece (eg. a cafe) and give a forecast for that location. I think this creates confusion, because it gives the impression of a bug and that the app can predict forecasts for other countries as well.

On the one hand, I want it to be specific enough to work for cities (eg. Athens), villages & neighborhoods (eg. Acropolis). On the other, not for minor locations (eg. cafes).

How can I go about fixing that? If somebody gives a very minor location or foreign city, I would like it to default to the capital city 'Athens', or somehow "broaden" the coordinates to the nearest city. Is there a way, to limit the coordinates somehow or filter the locations ? Is there a way to determine whether the coordinates are for a  minor or large location ?

Comment: Well I think you first need to decide what exactly you *want* the application to do in that case? Raise an error? Mention that it is in Greece? Something else? I think this is not much a technical issue, but more a "semantical" one?

Comment: If somebody gives a very minor location or foreign city, I would like it to default to the capital city 'Athens'. Or somehow "broaden" the coordinates to the nearest city.